# Multiple menus in one navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to create an Android application for different users (Guest, Member, Admin). I am using a navigation drawer in my app. I am wondering if I can create a menu for each user.

**Example:**

The guest menu can have three items: Log in, Sign up, Contact us.

The member menu can have different items: Profile, Log out.

The Admin menu can have: Manage Accounts, Add new members.

I want all these xml menus in one navigation drawer activity. and I want to change them according to the status of the user. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: create 3 menu files according to your accounts, and on login check your account and set its menu file accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create each menu for specific user. For example, if you have the following menu: `guest_menu`, `member_menu`, and `admin_menu`. You can easily use the menu with something like this:

```
// clear previous menu
navigationView.getMenu().clear();

switch (id) {
  case guest:
    navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.guest_menu);
    break;
  case member:
   navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.member_menu);
   break;
  case admin:
   navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.admin_menu);
   break;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your idea and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do is make 2 different arrays for Guest, Member, Admin in your String Array or you can make by arrayList for those. Like guestMenuList, memberMenuList, adminMenuList

Put condition in your Activity like this

```
if(isGuest){

   arrayList =  guestMenuList

}else if(isMember){

   arrayList =  memberMenuList

}else if(){

   arrayList =  adminMenuList

}
```

And attach this list into drawer adapter.